# CSS3: Using both SCSS and CSS variables

Tags: css, sass

I have two sets of variables:

```
/* CSS Variables */
:root {
    --black : #000000;
    --white : #FFFFFF;
    --primary : #2957C8;
}
```

and

```
/* SCSS variables from a variables.scss file */
$black: var(--black);
$white: var(--white);
$primary: var(--primary);
```

Both exist for some legacy reasons.
In many existing scss files, I found

```
@import '~variables.scss';
div {
  background: $white;
  color: $primary;
}
```

I could go to every file, swapping the scss variables for the css ones:

```
div {
  background: var(--white);
  color: var(--primary);
}
```

What would be the pros of doing so ?
I could eventually remove the `variables.scss` file.
It would remove all the `scss import`

Do you see any other pros ?

The issue here being that this set of colors is actually way bigger and shared by hundred of different projects. So I need to be 100% sure, doing the swap would be beneficial.

Comment: I really like to define locally scoped *css variables* like `--pading: 24px` and update them in *media queries*. I don't think that you can do that with Sass variables.